# File location with variable attribute

Tags: python, attachment, smtplib

I want to attach the newly created csv file for emailing from inside a program.
The filename is generated inside the program and stored as fname (a string).
How do I use that to mention the file location?

Will this work?

```
def emailing(fname, attachment)
    ...
    ...
    attachment = open(/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_MAX31855/%s, fname)
    ...
```

Comment: first try, later ask.

Comment: concatenate strings `"long/path/" + fname` or `"long/path/%s" % fname` or `"long/path/{}".format(fname)` or use special functions to concatenate path `os.path.join("long/path/", fname)`

Answer (score 1):

Use special function to concatenate path

```
open( os.path.join("long/path/", fname) )
```

Python doc: [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Eventually concatenate strings

```
open( "long/path/" + fname )
open( "long/path/%s" % fname )
open( "long/path/{}".format(fname) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use, `'{}'.format()` right after the location.

```
attachment = open('/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_MAX31855/{}'.format(fname))
```

To know More about .format refer here.
https://pyformat.info/

I suggest you learn basics of python first, before trying.

Comment: For file and folder paths, it's better to use the `os.path` utility functions because they make it easy to write code which is portable among OSs.